# Run two IOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have two iphone, 6 and 6 plus and I would like to ask if it's possible in xcode to run two iphone device at the same time with debugging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual devices?  Yes.  If you have both devices connected you'll see them both in the drop-down box at the top next to the Run button.  Just choose the device you want to run it on.  Nothing to prevent you running on both at once.  Or even one + the simulator.  I do it commonly.

Comment: I have run two device at the same time but only one device can access the log in the xcode for example I tapped the button that do this code print("log")

Comment: @SydneyLoteria You can debug against several devices at the same time and you can see the log of all of the devices. You just need to select the device in the debugger to see its log output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run same project in multiple connected device but can't use multiple simulator at same time.

:)